# Bivariate Probability

Tags: probability

If $X$ is the amount of money (in dollars) that a salesperson spends on gasoline during a day and $Y$ is the corresponding amount of money (in dollars) for which he or she is reimbursed, the joint probability density function of these two random variables is given by:

$f(x,y) = (1/25)((20-x)/(x))$ for $10 < x < 20, x/2 < y < x$, and $0$ everywhere else.

(a) Sketch the $\operatorname{supp}(X,Y)$. I got this part

(b) Find the marginal density function $g(x)$ for $X$. I got $g(x) = (2/5) - (x/50)$

(c) Find the conditional density function of $Y$ given $X = 12. h(y\mid x=12) = (1/4)((20-x)/(x))$

(d) Find the probability that the salesperson will be reimbursed at least $\$8$ when spending $12$ dollars.

I know I am suppose to use $P(Y \geq 8 \mid X = 12)$ which equals $P(Y \geq 8, X = 12)/P(X = 12)$ but I am not sure how to solve this one. Can someone explain this part to me?

Comment: I say draw the region with respect the x=12 and Y<8. then cross to the graph of f(x,y) to determine region of integration

Comment: However, X=12 for continues RV is seeming to be weird but, it is useful in some applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer for (b) is correct.

(c)

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{Y|X}(y|x) &=& \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} \\
&=& \dfrac{20-x}{25x}\bigg/ \dfrac{20-x}{50} \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{x} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{for $\frac{x}{2}\lt y\lt x$} \\
&& \\
\therefore\quad f_{Y|X}(y|12) &=& \dfrac{1}{6} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{for $6\lt y\lt 12$.}
\end{eqnarray*}

(d)

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y\geq 8\mid X=12) &=& \int_{y=8}^{12} f_{Y|X}(y|12)\;dy \\
&=& \int_{y=8}^{12} \dfrac{1}{6}\;dy \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{3}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks! I am following everything except. The bounds for the integral for the last part. My guess is since f(x|12) = 1/6 for 6 < y < 12 and P(Y > or = 8 | X = 12). Thus the bounds are between 8 and 12. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi @Mark Yes, that's right.